# Local node stuck 3.8 month behind (current height: 2504635)

Tags: monerod, synchronization, windows, error-log

I installed monero gui on **Windows** a week ago and created my first wallet, unfortunately I ran into an issue with my local node.

FYI, my monerod version is **0.17.3.0-release**

It does not synchronize all the way to the current node, it's currently lagging 3.8 month behind at node 2504635, and it's been four days.

It looks like there's a pattern visible in the logs:

- it's starting to synchronize with a remote node:

> I [104.140.201.42:18080 OUT] Sync data returned a new top block
> candidate: 2504635 -> 2587587 [Your node is 82952 blocks (3.8 months)
> behind]

- then there's an error log with the host a few seconds later:

> E [104.140.201.42:18080 OUT] Block is invalid or known without known type, dropping connection
> E Setting timer on a shut down object

- and then it starts all over again with the next host

I do not know where to start to try and fix this, for now I just cannot use Monero.
I have also seen a few of these errors in the log, not part of the main hell loop:

> [1648239176] libunbound[26980:0] error: can't bind socket: Permission
> denied. for 0.0.0.0
>
> 2022-03-25 20:11:09.717 I Target height decreasing from 2587588 to
> 2412596
>
> I Failed to invoke command 1001 return code -3
>
> COMMAND_HANDSHAKE invoke failed. (-3,
> LEVIN_ERROR_CONNECTION_DESTROYED)
>
> [23.88.121.112:18080 OUT] COMMAND_HANDSHAKE Failed
>
> W There were 0 blocks in the last 90 minutes, there might be large
> hash rate changes, or we might be partitioned, cut off from the Monero
> network or under attack, or your computer's time is off. Or it could
> be just sheer bad luck.

Remark: i do not wish to use a remote node, I want the blockchain locally for security purposes.

Comment: I went the route of deleting all node data (96% of the downloaded blockchain to the trash) and starting from scratch. It's been like two days, and it just went above the height I was. Looking good, we'll see.

Comment: Shoot, same player shoot again. Around the same height, just a few more blocks, I have the same issue. Is the Monero network under attack or something? Okay I guess I'll try a Linux box. But man that's fustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Final note: it finally worked at the third try, I first imported the available blockchain.raw on getmonero.org, and then the rest of the sync was ok.
I will just backup my current bitmonero folder in case this happens again.